# При передачи bytes в другое активити приложение закрывается, как исправить?

Tags: android

Пытаюсь передать byte[] в другое, но приложение просто закрывается, без ошибки. html - это очень длинная строка состоящая из html кода страницы

```
try {
            intent.putExtra("html", html.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Как это можно исправить или передать очень длинную строку в другой активити?

Когда пишешь через строку пишет;

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1174316)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ru.stopgame.artem.stopgame, PID: 24759
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
```

Comment: В районе 1MB ограничение.

Comment: @Suvitruf, другими словами. Мне никак не передать?

Comment: Вы можете сохранить в файл, и передавать путь к файлу. В открытой активити считать файл по этому пути.

Comment: @Suvitruf, мои любимые костыли. Спасибо

Comment: @chilo5432, это не костыль) Так концептуально правильнее - зачем целиком передавать данные между экранами, если можно только id/ссылку передать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, На мой не опытный взгляд использовать третий сервис, для передачи объекта это немного костыль, когда можно было бы если работало, просто передать данные через интент.